# How to fix an inconsistent accessibility error

Tags: c#, winforms

We are making a product invoice sheet - provides the item number, description, and price. I can't seem to get it to cooperate. I've gone through and made sure the class of InvItem is public but it's still giving me the same error code CS0050

```
 Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'List<InvIte>' is less accessible than method InvItemDB.GetItems()'
```

I've gone through the code and made sure it matches my textbook and that all classes are public.
This is only ONE part of my code --- it's not all 4 or 5 forms. If needed I can show those as well but this is the one that is giving the error message.

```
public partial class frmNewItem : Form
{
    public frmNewItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private InvItem item = null;

    public InvItem GetNewItem()
    {
        this.ShowDialog();
        return item;
    }



    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidData())
        {
            item = new InvItem(txtItemNo.Text, txtDescription.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice));
            this.Close();
        }
    }
 private bool IsValidData()
    {
        return Validator.IsPresent(txtItemNo) &&
               Validator.IsInt32(txtItemNo) &&
               Validator.IsPresent(txtDescription) &&
               Validator.IsPresent(txtPrice) &&
               Validator.IsDecimal(txtPrice);
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

InvItem Code:

```
class InvItem
{
    public string itemno;
    public string description;
    public decimal price;

    public InvItem()
    {
    }

    public InvItem(string itemno, string description, decimal price)
    {
        this.ItemNo = itemno;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public string ItemNo
    {
        get{return itemno;}
        set { itemno = value; }

    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }

    public string GetDisplayText()
    {
        return itemno + ", " + price.ToString("c") + ", " + description;
    }

    public string GetDisplayText(string sep)
    {
        return itemno + sep + price.ToString("c") + sep + description;
    }
```

Main form:

```
  public partial class frmInvMaint : Form
{

    public frmInvMaint()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<InvItem> products = null;


    private void frmInvMaint_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        products = InvItemDB.GetItems();
        FillItemListBox();
    }

    private void FillItemListBox()
    {
        lstItems.Items.Clear();
        foreach (InvItem p in products)
        {
            lstItems.Items.Add(p.GetDisplayText("\t"));
        }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmNewItem newItemForm = new frmNewItem();
        InvItem product = newItemForm.GetNewItem();
        if (product != null)
        {
            products.Add(product);
            InvItemDB.SaveItems(products);
            FillItemListBox();
        }
            }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = lstItems.SelectedIndex;
        if (i != -1)
        {
            InvItem product = (InvItem)products[i];
            string message = "Are you sure you want to delete " + product.Description + "?";
            DialogResult button =
                MessageBox.Show(message, "Confirm Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (button == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                products.Remove(product);
                InvItemDB.SaveItems(products);
                FillItemListBox();

            }
        }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

InvItemDB code:

```
  public static class InvItemDB
{
    private const string Path = @"..\..\InventoryItems.xml";

    public static List<InvItem> GetItems()
    {
        // create the list
        List<InvItem> items = new List<InvItem>();

        // create the XmlReaderSettings object
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
        settings.IgnoreComments = true;

        // create the XmlReader object
        XmlReader xmlIn = XmlReader.Create(Path, settings);

        // read past all nodes to the first Book node
        if (xmlIn.ReadToDescendant("Item"))
        {
            // create one Product object for each Product node
            do
            {
                InvItem item = new InvItem();
                xmlIn.ReadStartElement("Item");
                item.ItemNo = Convert.ToString(xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsInt());
                item.Description = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsString();
                item.Price = xmlIn.ReadElementContentAsDecimal();
                items.Add(item);
            }
            while (xmlIn.ReadToNextSibling("Item"));
        }

        // close the XmlReader object
        xmlIn.Close();

        return items;
    }

    public static void SaveItems(List<InvItem> items)
    {
        // create the XmlWriterSettings object
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = ("    ");

        // create the XmlWriter object
        XmlWriter xmlOut = XmlWriter.Create(Path, settings);

        // write the start of the document
        xmlOut.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Items");

        // write each product object to the xml file
        foreach (InvItem item in items)
        {
            xmlOut.WriteStartElement("Item");
            xmlOut.WriteElementString("ItemNo", Convert.ToString(item.ItemNo));
            xmlOut.WriteElementString("Description", item.Description);
            xmlOut.WriteElementString("Price", Convert.ToString(item.Price));
            xmlOut.WriteEndElement();
        }

        // write the end tag for the root element
        xmlOut.WriteEndElement();

        // close the xmlWriter object
        xmlOut.Close();
    }
```

The xml item list:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
       <ItemNo>3245649</ItemNo>
    <Description>Agapanthus</Description>
    <Price>7.95</Price>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ItemNo>3762592</ItemNo>
    <Description>Limonium</Description>
    <Price>6.95</Price>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ItemNo>9210584</ItemNo>
    <Description>Snail pellets</Description>
    <Price>12.95</Price>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ItemNo>4738459</ItemNo>
    <Description>Japanese Red Maple</Description>
    <Price>89.95</Price>
   </Item>
</Items>
```

I just need a dialog to show so I can enter in the item number, description, and price and save it to a new list.

Comment: Please show us `InvItemDB.GetItems` and `List`.  None of the code currently in the question appears relevant.

Comment: We can't see your InvItem type declaration, the error says that you must make it public as well.  Maybe you meant that method to be internal.

Comment: shouldn't `List<InvIte>` be `List<InvItem>` ?

Comment: Most probably you need to make `InvIte` class public. Or make the method `InvItemDB.GetItems` internal.

Comment: I missed an "m" while typing. It is InvItem

Comment: While we are looking at your code: even aside from the fact that you have forgotten to mark `InvItem` as `public` -- despite saying that you did not forget that in the question -- your code has a number of other bad practices which should be fixed.  Public fields are a bad code smell in C#; they should be properties. Methods which take `List<T>` but treat them as `IEnumerable<T>` should take `IEnumerable<T>`. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Next time please show the actual code that is failing. Your error message does not match the code you showed; there is no `GetItems` method in that code, and the enclosing type is not `InvItemDB`.  **Show the code that is failing, not unrelated code**.

My psychic powers are telling me:

- Type `InvItem` is internal (remember, the default accessibility if you say nothing is "internal" for a non-nested type declaration.)
- Method `InvItemDB.GetItems()` -- which, incidentally, should probably be a read-only property -- is a public method of a public class.

That's an inconsistency; you cannot have a public method on a public class that returns a list of internal-only items. The caller is not allowed to know about the existence of an internal-only type!

To fix it, remove the inconsistency. Either make `GetItems` internal, or make `InvItem` public.

> I've gone through and made sure the class of InvItem is public but it's still giving me the same error

Then do a clean rebuild and see if that fixes it. **Make sure you do not have two types both called `InvItem`.**

---

UPDATE: You said both:

"I've gone through and made sure the class of InvItem is public"

and

```
class InvItem { ... }
```

So no, you did not "make sure the class is public".  That needs to be

```
public class InvItem { ... }
```

This question should be closed and deleted.

Comment: updated. Sorry, I had posted the one that was giving the error but it wasn't enough.

Comment: Again, the default is internal, not public.